# Replace and/or remove first n occurrences of specific JSON key-value string from code file in PCRE Regex-supported Editors

Tags: regex, replace, pcre, find-occurrences

I have many PHP code files, where I have to find and replace/remove specific JSON key-value string from those PHP files with any text editors that support PCRE-Regex.

The string I have to find and remove (replace with nothing, not even space), that spans multiple lines (and indentation is 2 spaces but it could be 4 spaces too) looks like:

```
{
  label: "Other",
  value: "Other",
},
```

How can I remove first `(n)` occurrences of above string with PCRE-regex in Sublime Text editor/Notepad++ , such that it doesn't make any unexpected changes elsewhere in the file?

I am not so good with Regex on multiple occurrences and greedy-nongreedy matches, so any help is appreciated, though, I did try this one, but it didn't work:

```
(.*?):\"Other\",
```

Comment: Could you provide an example code with three blocks mentioned for `(n)` equal 2?

Comment: Also do you want to remove any key with value `"Other"`, or only certain keys?

Comment: @VickyDev Did the answer work out?

Comment: Yes it did, thanks for detailed explanation !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the example data, you might use

```
^{\R\h{2,}label:\h+"Other",\R\h{2,}value:\h+"Other",\R},
```

- `^{` Start of string and match `{`
- `\R\h{2,}` Match a newline, 2 or more horizontal whitespace chars
- `label:\h+"Other",` Match `label:` 1+ horizontal whitespace chars and `"Other,"`
- `\R\h{2,}` Match a newline and 2 horizontal whitespace chars
- `value:\h+"Other",`
- `\R},` Match an newline and `},`

Replace with an empty string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/knnOm3/1)

If `Other` can be other values, you might use

```
^{\R\h{2,}label:\h+"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*",\R\h{2,}value:\h+"[^"\\]*(?:\\.[^"\\]*)*",\R},
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/M1Kgen/1)